# when I execute the query i am getting the international descriptions in the national column?

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl3cV.png)

I have written the query to get only national calls and description.But,When I execute the below query.

I am getting the national and International.Below prefixes are for only to get the national.Please help me to solve the problem as I am new to SQL.

at National column which has zero that should no be print as they are international.

```
select ce.destination_descr,ce.duration,
      if (length(ce.destination_number)>5 
          and (ce.destination_number REGEXP '32|3246|3247|3248|3249|3270|3277|3278|32900|32901|32902|32903|32904|32905|32906|32907|32908|32909|1207|1307|1407|1204|1304|1404|1200|1300|1400|1299|1399|1499|100|119'),
          ce.cost,0) as national 
from symphonica_cdr_event ce 
join order_process op on op.order_id=ce.order_id 
where op.invoice_id=8604
```

Comment: Can you try and explain this in terms of SQL? That's a gigantic query that needs to be reduced to a more minimal form.

Comment: we need to print the national calls based on the given number in destination_number.

Comment: You've given zero example data, so it's anyone's guess if this is correct or not.

Comment: By using the table (in the image) I need to get the description as starts with "Belgium" using these prefixes in the query

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to get only those calls information with having destination_number in the prefixes above. To achieve this, you should use the compare in the where clause like 
where ce.destination_number  REGEXP '32|3246|32..' and also the length condition should be after where clause.
i.e something like this.

```
    select ce.destination_descr,ce.duration,ce.cost from symphonica_cdr_event ce join order_process op on op.order_id=ce.order_id where op.invoice_id=8604 and length(ce.destination_number)>5 and ce.cost>0
and (ce.destination_number REGEXP '^(32|3246|3247|3248|3249|3270|3277|3278|32900|32901|32902|32903|32904|32905|32906|32907|32908|32909|1207|1307|1407|1204|1304|1404|1200|1300|1400|1299|1399|1499|100|119)')
```

Comment: update the query, let me know if thats the requirement.

Comment: I am getting the internatinal descriptions and we need to display the cost also

Comment: add ce.cost to the select. If the results are wrong then there might be issue with regex, you will have to post sample data to ensure correctness

Comment: I am getting the cost for national and international with description.Same issue as before no change after adding your query

Comment: How do you distinguish a national and international call? Give sample data, or explain what you are trying to do with that REGEX.

Comment: could you please check latest image.In that the national column which has zero that description should not print

Comment: You have to give us sample data to help you then.

Comment: Sample data means Do i need to give my database table?

Comment: Yes, few records atleast and the expected output

Comment: in the attached image you can check the output what i need and the column national is  '0'.Those descriptions should not be print.

Comment: You are using if( condition, ce.cost ,0) which means if the condition is true, it will print ce.cost otherwise it will print 0 for all other rows, please reiterate your requirement of what you need.

Comment: If you dont want to print them, use the same conditions in where clause

Comment: can you share your mail id so that i can explain you more in clear way.

Comment: I sent you mail.could you please check and give me reply